# Rails dynamic foreign key for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I have a User model that's used to hold all Users. There's two types on users in my apps, mentors and students, but they have the same structure.

I want to do something like this.

```
has_many :requests, :foreign_key => mentor? ? 'mentor_id' : 'student_id', :class_name => 'Request'
```

I have the mentor? method in the model but it gives me a method_missing error. I'm assuming it's because it's looking for the method in `dynamic_matchers.rb`

This is the error it gives

`/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in 'method_missing': undefined method 'mentor?' for #<Class:0x00000001b40630> (NoMethodError)`

Is there a way to go about this without making a seperate models for the Student and Mentor? I feel that'd it be unnecessary seeing that they both use the same fields.

Comment: Why do you want different id columns? This logic should be on the user model alone, and not on requests. Also what you want is not possible... :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so let me correct that: this is not possible, and even if in a utopian world it was or you found a workaround for this, it is certainly **not correct**.

What you are in fact looking for is a mix between **inheritance** (STI or Single Table Inheritence in Rails) and **polymorphism**.

## **How can you implement this the right way?**

You have a **user** model, **Students** and **Mentors** ar both **Users** so they will both **inherit** for this model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Student < User
end

class Mentor < User
end
```

What does it implies? Well it implies that the User model holds (without you doing anything else) a field **type** wich will either contain 'Student' or 'Mentor' or nothing depending on how you initialize your object:

```
user = User.create()
student = Student.create()
mentor = Mentor.create()
```

Now, your **Request** can either belong to a **Student** or to a **Mentor**. So here you could set a polymorphic association like so:

```
class Student < User
  has_many :requests, as: :owner
end

class Mentor < User
  has_many :requests, as: :owner
end

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now you can write:

```
student.requests
mentor.requests
request.owner
```

Comment: The Request belongs to both the mentor and student. How would I go about doing this? How does Rails know if it's a student or a mentor?

Comment: I just googled single table inheritance, thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about what do you need.
Same model structure, and one user can be a mentor for many students? and one student can have one mentor? is that?

if it is, what about a self join?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "mentor_id"
  belongs_to :mentor, :class_name => "User"
end
```

this way you will be able to call student.mentor and mentor.students

Comment: I have student-mentor relationships in another Model since mentors can have multiple students.

Comment: but the way i posted, you also can have multiple students associated with one mentor =)

Comment: Sorry for bother!, Sparda already answered, and i did not see it in the tag search.